# Tutorials or books on kernel programming for OpenCL?

Tags: kernel, opencl, gpgpu

The question is specific enough I suppose. Just to make it clear:

- I am not looking for a reference, but a tutorial.
- I am interested specifically in the kernel programming aspect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't that many books out there so you can't be very picky. There are two that are more like guides and less like a reference:

- [OpenCL in Action](http://www.manning.com/scarpino2/)
- [Heterogeneous Computing with OpenCL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123877660)

They both cover more than just kernel programming, like the basics of parallel computing and how graphic cards work, etc. but they do contain lots of example OpenCL kernel code.

Comment: thx. Also, a link I got from asking the question on Twitter: http://www.streamcomputing.eu/education/self-study/

Comment: also, I realized that libraries for specific hardware (CUDA for NVIDIA) bring handy pre-packaged functions. For matrix calculus, this means that you work directly on a whole matrix, without the need to chop it in vectors of size 16 max as would be necessary for pure OpenCL (if I understood well!). Resources for NVIDIA's CUDA: http://t.co/zEjw6VHL

Comment: I second *OpenCL in Action*; I've read that one, *Heterogeneous computing with OpenCL* and *OpenCL Programming Guide* and think the first one is the best as tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I'd throw in [OpenCl Programming Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321749642). Approximately one-third of the book is a compilation of nine end-to-end OpenCL 1.1 case studies of various complexity, each including fine grain details like kernel listings.

Although some people have pointed at multiple shortcomings of this text, I personally see a value in going thru some case studies in the book for grasping of this awesome technology.